# open source blogging platform for private / password-protected blogs

Tags: gratis, open-source, web-apps, blog

I'm looking for a web-based open-source blogging platform (like WordPress but with some special specifications) that can provide a timeline-like interface viewable only to logged-in users. I need to deploy it on our company's own server and .Net or PHP is preferred. I'm trying to use this software as a daily employee journaling system, a tool for team update/sync, a way of informing supervisors, archiving previous efforts, and a Knowledge Management tool. It's highly important to me for it to be deployable on-premises and web-based, preferably offering a mobile interface too. I found several platforms but are either cloud-based or proprietary, such as BlogIn.

Do you recommend anything?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
I did some more searching and came across Friendica, Mastodon, Pump.io, Hubzilla, and Diaspora. Friendica seems to be the best choice so far but I'm still indecisive.

**Edit**

We got a Windows server environment on a bare metal server located in the office, mostly used for .Net applications, and we've recently got a php Cpanel host for our billing and stuff. So as long as we can set it up we're good to go. We also have an Ubuntu server VM but it's not faced to the internet so people won't be able to use stuff hosted on it from outside the company's network, although it's proven itself to be the best environment to setup best available solutions on

Comment: Do you have a budget, or must it be [tag:gratis] ?

Comment: I hate to admit it but it almost certainly should be gratis

Comment: That's ok,, I messed up by not noticing the [tag:open-source] tag. I have commented a few today from new posters reminding them that the more info they give the better we can help them. I guess yours flew by on auto-pilot, as [tag:gratis] is understood when using [tag:open-source]. Btw, I once asked on Meta about introducing a [Tag to indicate that an app is free for commercial use](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/tag-to-indicate-that-an-app-is-free-for-commercial-use), but the idea got shot down. Anyway, your question is fine as it stands. Good luck :-)

Comment: Hmmm, do you have any requirements for data storage? E.g a specific database (MySql, etc), plain tetx fiels (NoSql) ...

Comment: We got a Windows server environment on a bare metal server located in the office, mostly used for .Net applications, and we've recently got a php cpanel host for our billing and stuff. So as long as we can set it up we're good to go. We also have an Ubuntu server VM but it's not faced to the internet so people won't be able to use stuff hosted on it from outside the company's network, although it's proven itself to be the best environment to setup best available solutions on.

Comment: Can you edit that into the question? Not everyone might read the comments, and, if they miss this, you might not get a good answer.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Sure thing. Although I don't believe I'm going to receive any more answers